# Official Redux documentation on reducer manager not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Following the [example on reducer manager](https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting#using-a-reducer-manager) results in `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` with the following code:

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_REDUCER') {
    store.reducerManager.add('itworks', myreducer)
  }
}
```

The `console.log(store)` shows that only `getState` and `dispatch` are available on `store` even though I have followed the example using:

```
store.reducerManager = reducerManager
```

Is the documentation wrong or am doing something wrong? And if im doing it wrong what do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Your middleware function does not actually receive the store as an argument: `It only exposes a subset of the store API to the middleware: dispatch(action) and getState().` documentation [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware)

Comment: So I should import the "actual" store into the file that creates the middleware and then I can get my code working?

Comment: No.  Don't import the store into middleware.  You shouldn't be trying to attach custom functions to the store that way anyway.

Comment: From the document action that is my understanding on how to dynamically add and remove reducers. Is there another way you say?

Comment: It looks like reducer manager example is for code splitting, for example when you want to lazy load an admin module that will add reducers when a user clicks on the admin menu.